# GCE import custom windows image

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I followed Packer documentation and built a Windows 2012R2 VM, converted to RAW, tar'd up and uploaded to a google cloud bucket.  I then created the VM image off of that.

Why won't my VM boot?    There is almost no windows documentation in GCP

Comment: You have provided no information in your question. Questions must be self contained. If you following steps in a guide, list those steps in your question. There is a lot of documentation for importing Windows images, including a Google Tool to automate this for you. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks

Comment: Useless support.   I am done with this.

Comment: We are not your support. Stackoverflow consists of volunteers that have an interest in helping others.